# Gltf 2.0 file imported from Polycam has strange holes in texture, but only when connected to the emission socket

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, gltf, photogrammetry

I photoscanned a hallway and imported it into blender. It looks fine at first but when I try to connect the diffuse texture to the emission socket, random patches of the of the mesh do not emit, and these patches seem to correspond to the separate pieces of geometry that make up the model. Some other observations I have made are that there are three images that are imported with this model, each of them different. Each island on each of the three textures has a corresponding UV island, but since there is only one UV map many of the islands are overlapped.

Below are images of: a selected chunk of unconnected geometry matching with the no-emission area, examples of two of the textures sharing the same UV map with overlapping islands, and a screenshot of my viewport and material setup.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found what it was, I had not noticed that the model had multiple materials assigned to different chunks of the mesh. So to edit the material of the whole thing you have to do it for all the materials.[image]

Comment: I discovered this today too. I need to figure out a way to bake all the materials into one, but am really having a lot of trouble, I tried this, but the material just ends up a big black square: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VS4rqkqmg7Y

Comment: On another note, I love the way the scans look after using polycam, but I might have to go back to using 3D Scanner App if I get these weird mesh issues (it just means doing a lot of manual tidying after)